# How to Move WorkSpace windows? How to move Show Applications?

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

I am new to Ubuntu, Mostly work off Manjaro.

I am trying to move the WorkSpace Menu to either the tool bar or to the far left of the screen when it comes up underneath the activities bar?  Is this possible? I have gnome tweak tools installed and working but I don't see anything under the workspace tab to change anything other than how many windows and such.  Thanks in advance.

I mostly work off Manjaro but I am trying to get familiar with the Ubuntu Family.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "workspace menu"?